# CRM 2013 - Retrieve the value of the OOB "customerid" field

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using a plugin to create a custom ticket number, but I am having trouble retrieving the selected user in the "Customer" field. How can I get the selected value from the OOB "Case" entity that appears to be referencing the OOB "Contact" entity? I keep having "Microsoft.XRM.Sdk.EntityReference" returned into my string. lol.

```
var custName = myEntity.Attributes["customerid"]; <--nope
var custName = myEntity["customerid"]; <--nope
var custName = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("customerid"); <--I had high hopes for this, but only get a blank value. :(
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customerid` field is a lookup so it's normal that server-side you get an `EntityReference`. The correct way is this one

```
EntityReference customerRef = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("customerid");
string customerName = customerRef.Name;
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but I'm only getting a blank value. I did looked further at the OOB Contact entity and I think the composite field may be part of the problem? Default it is called "fullname", but when I try to reference it, I get the "..key not in dictionary.." error. Any ideas?

Comment: if you get a blank value you can always retrieve the contact/account entity, something like Entity customer = service.Retrieve(customerRef.LogicalName, customerRef.Id, new ColumnSet(true)); and get the field values from the customer entity

Comment: Not sure why I had to jump through all those hoops, but that did the trick. Thank you for your help @Guido